# Getting rid of "-------------"/outlining??? in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Someone came to my desk to help me debug something, and maybe with some keystrokes, they turned something on that reminds me of the paragraph symbol in word where you can see all spaces by a "-".  It's kind of annoying me.  I don't think it's the RightClick->Outlining window, but some other command.  Does someone know how to turn it off?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit > Advanced > View White Space

Comment: Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W on my machine. Might depend on which personality you selected when you installed VS, whether or not you have add-ons like ReSharper, etc. The menu will work consistently, though.